# Using a Markup Extension as value of property Setter in XAML. {0} is not valid for Setter.Value. The only supported MarkupExtension types are

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, markup-extensions

Below is a very small example how to get this `exception`. This is already a known issue (for more than 7 years!). Is there already a solution for that?

---

#### Exception

> FooExtension is not valid for Setter.Value. 
>   The only supported MarkupExtension types are
>   DynamicResourceExtension and BindingBase or derived types.

#### C# Class

```
public class FooExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Key));
    }
}
```

*This is not the original class/MarkupExtension I'm using, but the logic (return `SolidColorBrush`) are identical and it gives exactly the same error/behavior.*

- Exception during design time
- Exception in designer gone after rebuild solution
- No problems in runtime

#### XAML usage

```
Background="{extensions:Foo Key=#FFF37C21}"
```

---

The `extension` worked until yesterday for more than 1 year! Including every Windows, VisualStudio or any other update! And now since 1 day I got this bug behavior during the design time!

Im using:

- **VS15.7.3**
- .NET Framework 4.7.02556

Sources:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/931d7bff-90b6-4a70-bb0b-3a097e1301a1/net-40-breaking-change-using-a-markup-extension-as-value-of-property-setter-in-xaml-style?forum=wpf
- [.NET 4.0 Breaking Change - Using a Markup Extension as Value of Property Setter in XAML Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650646/net-4-0-breaking-change-using-a-markup-extension-as-value-of-property-setter)
- [{0} is not valid for Setter.Value. The only supported MarkupExtension types are DynamicResourceExtension and BindingBase or derived types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881020/0-is-not-valid-for-setter-value-the-only-supported-markupextension-types-are)

---

#### Binding Workaround (not working)

On some pages it is said that you should use `binding`. But there I got the same error/behavior!

btw. I use this markup extension in a `Storyboard`, so I can't return a `binding` anyway.

```
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {            
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Source = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Key));

        return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! I was a kind of `XAML Resources` relationship. I defined a `ResourceDictionary` inside of `App.xaml` which was already defined in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` as a `XmlnsPrefix` / `XmlnsDefinition`!